# 1 for r relation in a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table in my mysql database that one of the fields create a relation 1 --> N for other table.

My query is:

```
select    
rc.trial_id,
(select label from vocabulary_interventioncode where id = (select interventioncode_id from repository_clinicaltrial_i_code where clinicaltrial_id = rc.id limit 1)) as interventioncode
from 
repository_clinicaltrial rc;
```

i am using:

```
(select label from vocabulary_interventioncode where id = (select interventioncode_id from repository_clinicaltrial_i_code where clinicaltrial_id = rc.id limit 1))
```

with **limit 1** on the table *vocabulary_interventioncode* to do not get a error on the query.

Is it possible to concat all the results of the query:

```
(select label from vocabulary_interventioncode where id = (select interventioncode_id from repository_clinicaltrial_i_code where clinicaltrial_id = rc.id))
```

and put all the results in a single column ?

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you want to get for it.

Comment: today (with limit 1) i get "Drugs" or "Procedu" or "Equipament". I want to get: "Drugs, Procedu, Equipament"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT   rc.trial_id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(vi.label)
FROM     repository_clinicaltrial rc
JOIN     repository_clinicaltrial_i_code rcic ON rcic.clinicaltrial_id = rc.id
JOIN     vocabulary_interventioncode vi ON vi.id = rcic.interventioncode_id 
GROUP BY rc.trial_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select    
rc.trial_id,
(select label from vocabulary_interventioncode where id = (select interventioncode_id from repository_clinicaltrial_i_code where clinicaltrial_id = rc.id limit 1)) as interventioncode
from 
repository_clinicaltrial rc;
```

This can be better written as a join. You might want to use `left join` if you want to show trials with no codes.

```
select
  rc.trial_id
  vic.label as interventioncode
from repository_clinicaltrial rc
join repository_clinicaltrial_i_code rcic on rcic.clinicaltrial_id = rc.id
join vocabulary_interventioncode vic on vic.id = rcic.interventioncode_id
```

You will get several rows for each trial. We can get one row for each trial with all their intervention codes concatenated together with [`group_concat`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/).

```
select
  rc.trial_id
  group_concat(
    distinct vic.label
    order by vic.label
    separator ','
  ) as intervention_codes
from repository_clinicaltrial rc
join repository_clinicaltrial_i_code rcic on rcic.clinicaltrial_id = rc.id
join vocabulary_interventioncode vic on vic.id = rcic.interventioncode_id
group by rc.trial_id
```